# CSS Style not reaching edges

Tags: css, border, whitespace, edges

On my website, the header is a div tag with a coloured background. The only problem is that it doesn't reach the "edges" of the window (Please see http://manpoints.uk.to/).

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Thanks, Josh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try what @KP is suggesting, plus add `#header{ width:100%; }` to your stylesheet. What's happening is that your header does not have a defined width, and it's taking te maximum width of the content inside.

Comment: It's working thank you, I wanted it to reach the absolute top of the page. I'm now trying to center my actual page but not too sure how.

Comment: You're welcome. I saw you were using `<body align='center'>` or something. I really suggest you to move on to CSS.. a great way to learn is through w3schools.com .. Good luck =)

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser default css.

Add this to the head

```
<style>
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
```

Or add it to a style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a `CSS reset` technique to clear all browser-set styles. Your issue is that `body` by default has `margin` and `padding`.

In your stylesheet be sure to clear them by:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

See this question for relevant CSS reset stylesheets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: How do I align the body in the center?

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease not 100% exactly what you're going for, but if you just want your text content to be centered in its div, you can simply use `text-align: center;` in your #content CSS style.

Comment: I mean in the sense that my site is all on the left hand side. An example of what I would like is shown at https://www.dream-hosting.co.uk/